# A question on the permutations of arranging 6 people around a table.

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm working on a question that involves six people needing to be seated around a table and asks how many arrangements are possible if it is only interested in who sits next to whom, not where they sit at the table?

I wasn't able to come up with the correct answer based on their solution, but I'm having trouble understanding the thought behind what they've done. I've included the image of the solution to this problem and was wondering if someone can help me understand what they've done?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically asking for a distribution which doesn't depend on the absolute position, rather the *relative* position. That's easy.

Assume a random person $p_1$ sat at the start of a straight line. Then there are $5$ possiblities for the person who sits on his right, $p_2$, then $4$ possiblityies for the one who sits on *his* right, $p_3$, and so on. So, we get

$\begin{align}p_1\quad&p_2\quad&p_3\quad&p_4\quad&p_5\quad&p_6\\1\quad&5\quad&4\quad&3\quad&2\quad&1\end{align}$

So, the number is $5*4*\cdots*1=120$.

But, ABCDEF is the same as FEDCBA, since, in both, A is between B and F, B is between A and C, and so on. So, the final number is ${120\over2}=60$